# Sorting names(Chinese and English) using Sqlite

Tags: c, database, sqlite

How can I get contact names (English and Chinese) sorted in acceding order but in each alphabet group Chinese names displays first the English one.

For example if I have contacts in DB as below:

**`CName     CNamePinin`**

`AAA        AAA`

`ABB        ABB`

`伺候       ABC`

`苹果       APPLE`

`Axx        AXX`

`久了     AZZ`

... similar combination with other alphabets

How I can get result as below using Sqlite3

**`CName     CNamePinin`**

`苹果      APPLE`

`久了      AZZ`

`伺候      ABC`

`AAA       AAA`

`ABB       ABB`

`Axx       AXX`

... and so on.

**Tried:**

```
SELECT CName, CNamePinin 
FROM CTable WHERE CNamePinin LIKE 'A%' 
ORDER BY CName COLLATE UNICODE DESC
```

**NOTE : CNamePinYin is equivalent English name for Chinese names**
Thanks :)

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you got your input and output mixed up? As the desired output is definitely not sorted

Comment: I have tried below query :

SELECT CName, CNamePinin FROM CTable WHERE CNamePinin LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY FName COLLATE UNICODE DESC
But this has to run in a loop for 26 times that is what I don't want.
I am looking for optimized solution. @jhhoff02

Comment: With this query I can get output for any particular alphabet "SELECT CName, CNamePinin FROM CTable WHERE CNamePinin LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY FName COLLATE UNICODE DESC" but I want it for all alphabets without using this query in a loop. @ChrisTurner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say whether this is entirely correct since your definition of what the table looks like differs from the SQL you've given, but it looks like what you're after is to sort by the first character of CNamePinin - in which case you could do this:

```
SELECT CName, CNamePinin FROM CTable ORDER BY substr(CNamePinin,1,1),FName COLLATE UNICODE DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your help. I find that this query doesn't work properly. Order by clause work on UNICODE ascending right ? If we do Order by FName. But when we do Order by FName COLLATE UNICODE DESC English and Chinese contacts are getting mixed up for some alphabets. Query works fine if out required as All English Names should come first then Chinese for each alphabets.

Comment: @srb_programming you've said that CNamePinin is meant to contain English so UNICODE shouldn't be an issue unless you're saying that your original SQL also wasn't sorting correctly?

Comment: If we remove COLLATE UNICODE I find it working.
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah when I looked into with variety of contacts I found that it is not  working in some case. Actually multi ordering might have issue in this case since we are ordering it alphabetically on CNamePinYin and then ordering it on  CName (It has actual Chinese and English names). So whenever I apply UNICODE I get mixed CName but after removing this I get accumulated output.

Comment: The SQLite FAQ does mention that its default support for Unicode comparison is limited so maybe that's the problem you're running in to? But (and I've never done this personally) it does seem to suggest it's possible to write your own comparison routines and use them instead